# Using JSpinner to get values

Tags: java, swing, date, simpledateformat, jspinner

I am using `JSpinner` for selecting time in HH:MM:SS format. Whenever 
i open the GUI the spinner sets automatically to current system time,
What I need is say for example if I click save after giving some value to spinner and when
I again open it the old values should be shown.

I have tried following code but its not working,

```
if(Stime != null){
            Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMMSS", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(Stime);
            StarttimeSpinner.setValue(time);
}
```

where Stime is the previously saved time in HHMMSS format e.g(142030)

is it correct? or how can i do it? Please help!

EDIT:

```
    SpinnerModel Startmodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
    StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner();
    StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner(Startmodel);
    JComponent editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(StarttimeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
    StarttimeSpinner.setEditor(editor);

   try{ 
        if(!(Stime.equalsIgnoreCase("")))
            {
            Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(Stime);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
            String dateString = formatter.format(time);
            StarttimeSpinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));

        }
    }
    }catch(Exception ie){
        System.err.println("in time panel");
    }
```

Stime format is HHmmss and its a string.In dateString(Variable) i get the previous value in HH:mm:ss format but its not being set in Spinner instead showing the system time.

**EDIT 2:**
I have Found out a solution but with a bug,

If my code is like this(1),

```
 StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner();
             SpinnerModel Startmodel = new SpinnerDateModel();
            StarttimeSpinner = new JSpinner(Startmodel);
            JComponent editor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(StarttimeSpinner, "HH:mm:ss");
            StarttimeSpinner.setEditor(editor);
```

The below piece of code works fine,

```
Date starttime = new Date();
starttime = (Date)StarttimeSpinner.getValue();
```

if i change the code like below(2),

```
Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(Stime);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");  
        String dateString = formatter.format(time);
        StarttimeSpinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));
```

where Stime is (e.g)120011

The below piece of code doesn't work fine,

```
Date starttime = new Date();
starttime = (Date)StarttimeSpinner.getValue();
```

and throwing Exception as `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date` at get value statement.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: When you say saved do you mean that you close the entire program and when you open it again, you want that time displayed? If that's the case, you need to save it to a text file or something of the sort. and load the file when opening the program

Comment: So, does anything go wrong?

Comment: @peeskillet No am not closing entire program just the GUI of spinner alone . I have the previous value in Stime variable but i dont know how to set it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I dont see any changes the system time is set again

Comment: Make sure that the spinner is setup correctly to take a `Date` value.  Make sure that the `String` value is been parsed correctly. Make sure that the value is within the acceptable range of the spinner. Make sure that the spinner's value isn't been changed some time after this call...

Comment: @MadProgrammer  i set Jspinner to 00:00:00. after i parse as i showed in snippet above i noticed the value of time is "Mon Dec 01 00:00:00 IST 1969" its showing 4 minutes less than system time now when i opened GUI again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer EDIT 2

Comment: @user3164187 Why are you suprised? You passed the field a `String` value, but try and get the value back as `Date` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly 100% sure what you're trying to acheive, but take a look at the example below, maybe it will help you out. I use a button to set the date, then another button that pops up a `JOptionPane` that shows the previous date saved from the first button click.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TimeSpinner {

    Date date;
    JButton setDate = new JButton("Set Date");
    JButton showSpinner = new JButton("Show Spinner");
    JTextField jtfDate = new JTextField(15);
    JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
    JPanel panel;

    public TimeSpinner() {
        jtfDate.setEditable(false);

        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(setDate, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(jtfDate, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(showSpinner, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setDate.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                date = new Date();
                jtfDate.setText(date.toString());
            }
        });
        showSpinner.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (date != null) {
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                String dateString = formatter.format(date);
                spinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, spinner, "Spinner:"
                        ,JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Date Spinner Demo");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new TimeSpinner();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

With the following code, I was able to achieve this using the a the `SpinnerModel`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String dateString = formatter.format(date);
spinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString}));
```

---

**EDIT**

For different formatting, just change the format. If you want in time

- For hours in 24 hour mode `"HH:mm:ss"`
- For 12 hour mode `"hh:mm:ss a"`

Comment: with respect to your above code , When i click on set date in GUI i get Mon Jan 06 11:12:43 IST 2014 and in spinner it shows 01/06/14 . I changed SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); to SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HHMMSS"); to get 11:12:43 or like 111243 i mean the time alone. but its giving some different values. is it possible to get?

Comment: You just need to change the date format. It was a quick program I put together. Just fix the formatting accordingly to the desired format. The format I used was `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. I could've easily made it `"dd/MM/yyy"`

Comment: Use `"hh:mm:ss a"`. Capital letters mean something different

Comment: with your code it is working fine. I dont know what is wrong in my EDIT code. Am i initializing and setting values to Jspinner correctly?

Comment: StarttimeSpinner.setModel(new SpinnerListModel(new String[]{dateString})); This line of code is not setting the value to spinner

Comment: Try putting a `System.out.println(dateString)` after `String dateString = formatter.format(time);`. Maybe the `if` block is not being executed